# C functions returning an array

Tags: arduino, atmega

Sorry for the post. I have researched this but..... still no joy in getting this to work. There are two parts to the question too. Please ignore the code TWI Reg code as its application specific I need help on nuts and bolts C problem.

So... to reduce memory usage for a project I have started to write my own TWI (wire.h lib) for ATMEL328p. Its not been put into a lib yet as '1' I have no idea how to do that yet... will get to that later and '2'its a work in progress which keeps getting added to.

The problem I'm having is with reading multiple bytes.

**Problem 1**
I have a function that I need to return an Array

```
byte *i2cBuff1[16];

void setup () {
    i2cBuff1 =  i2cReadBytes(mpuAdd, 0x6F, 16);
}

/////////////////////READ BYTES////////////////////
byte* i2cReadBytes(byte i2cAdd, byte i2cReg, byte i2cNumBytes) {
    static byte result[i2cNumBytes];
    for (byte i = 0; i < i2cNumBytes; i ++) {
      result[i] += i2cAdd + i2cReg;
   }

    return result;
}
```

What I understand  :o ) is I have declared a **Static byte array** in the function which I **point** to as the **return argument** of the function. 
The function call requests the return of a **pointer** value for a byte array which is supplied.

Well .... it doesn't work .... I have checked multiple sites and I think this should work. The error message I get is:

```
MPU6050_I2C_rev1:232: error: incompatible types in assignment of 'byte* {aka unsigned char*}' to 'byte* [16] {aka unsigned char* [16]}'
 i2cBuff1 =  i2cReadBytes(mpuAdd, 0x6F, 16);
```

**Problem 2**
Ok say IF the code sample above worked. I am trying to reduce the amount of memory that I use in my sketch. By using any memory in the function even though the memory (need) is released after the function call, the function must need to reserve an amount of 'space' in some way, for when the function is called. Ideally I would like to avoid the use of static variables within the function that are duplicated within the main program.

Does anyone know the trade off with repeated function call.... i.e looping a function call with a bit shift operator, as apposed to calling a function once to complete a process and return ... an Array? Or was this this the whole point that C does not really support Array return in the first place.

Hope this made sense, just want to get the best from the little I got.

BR
Danny

Comment: Questions seeking debugging help ("why isn't this code working?") must include the desired behavior, a specific problem or error and the shortest code necessary to reproduce it in the question itself. Questions without a clear problem statement are not useful to other readers. See: How to create a Minimal, Complete, and Verifiable example.

Comment: @Olaf, you forgot to add the link this time. Asker, please [look here!](http://stackoverflow.com/help/mcve)

Comment: Thanks Olaf.....I will edit the question

Comment: I think you can return with return &(result[0]). (If you fix size cz variable length problem as Barmar mentioned) But I dont understand what you are trying to achieve.if You got already buffer with enough size . Just fill it inside function and use.

Answer (score 1):

This line:

```
byte *i2cBuff1[16];
```

declares `i2cBuff1` as an array of 16 `byte*` pointers. But `i2cReadBytes` doesn't return an array of pointers, it returns an array of bytes. The declaration should be:

```
byte *i2cBuff1;
```

Another problem is that a static array can't have a dynamic size. A variable-length array has to be an automatic array, so that its size can change each time the function is called. You should use dynamic allocation with `malloc()` (I used `calloc()` instead because it automatically zeroes the memory).

```
byte* i2cReadBytes(byte i2cAdd, byte i2cReg, byte i2cNumBytes) {
    byte *result = calloc(i2cNumBytes, sizeof(byte));
    for (byte i = 0; i < i2cNumBytes; i ++) {
      result[i] += i2cAdd + i2cReg;
   }

    return result;
}
```

Comment: Hi Barmer , Thanks for the reply, I tried your solution but got the result......MPU6050_I2C_rev1:361: error: storage size of 'result' isn't constant
   static byte result[i2cNumBytes]; ..... Is late and will look again tomorrow thanks for the input    
                                 ^

Comment: Added the fix for that to the answer.

Comment: Any C tutorial should explain `malloc` and `calloc`.

Comment: Ok.... I have not used malloc before, but have seen it in a few example sketches. I thought it...  memory allocated... something ?? not sure what or why you would need to do it if variables were assigned. But you have used calloc..... ? Call location ? complete guess.... need sleep... thank for your help so far. I don't want to sell my self short I did look at many C examples.... but no result for what I wanted. Many examples are not so good on the internet

Comment: for pointers and arrays.... I followed this.. no work! and looked at many others. but still. what is the best. Even if you find a way maybe something is better. Many people on here do not like answers.. just laugh at the learner.....

Comment: look at them scared of my 90 stars hahahahahaha

Comment: I'm sorry, this is not the place to try to teach you the basics of C programming with pointers. FYI, "alloc" is short for "allocate", because these functions allocate memory.